# Add a Subview to a UITableView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have been trying to add a subview to a UITableView (not a UITableViewCell, but the UITableView itself) in storyboard. It seems like the only views that can be added to the UITableView in storyboard are the tableheaderview and the tablefooterview. I have done pretty extensive research and I do believe that this is the best approach (as opposed to adding a view above the UITableView). I need to be able to tap buttons on the view but also have it scroll the tableview when touches are on the UIView. But, I want to use storyboards.

Is this possible in storyboard? (if so, how?)

Is this ill-advised for some reason (if so, alternative suggestion would be appreciated)

Comment: Use a `UIScrollView`. Why do you want to use a `UITableView`. Do you want to add cells too?

Comment: I have a complete UITableView. It us grouped and uses several different types of cells.

Comment: What is your usecase like? Why and where do you want to add a view to your table view?

Comment: It will start in the middle of the tableview (I will make space for it). It will scroll with the tableview and stop at a certain point. It needs to scroll with the tableview and it needs to scroll the tableview. It also needs to have subviews that are tappable themselves.

Comment: I think we can add the custom view(which contains the object you wanted) in the same view that holds the table view above the table view.

Comment: I mean, not adding the custom view as the subview to the table view but to the container of the table view. What you think ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I didn't think if you added a subview to a tableHeaderView and then move it outside of the bounds of that view that it would be visible.

Comment: I get it. But in order for the subview to scroll the tableview, it needs to be added to the tableview. There are ways to pass touches through all points on the added view except its subviews so as not to disable them, but when those subviews (buttons, segmented controls, etc) are first touched in a scrolling action, they will not respond and pass the scroll through to the tableview if the view is not a subview of the tableview itself.

Comment: Okay, i mentioned not like adding subview to the tableView.tableHeaderView but to the view that holds the table view.

Comment: And managing the cases and bound and scroll properties there. Okay i seen that, good approch.

Comment: Back to my original question, is this possible in storyboard. I can achieve what I want without storyboard but I would like to use it.

Comment: My doubt is that, is that a stationary view or moving with the table view scroll?